# Realize a recursion within several functors

Tags: recursion, module, ocaml, functor

I have built several modules including `EEA` which match module type `PROP`. Now I would like to build 2 functors which looks like follows:

```
(* zone.ml *)
module type ZONE =
sig
  ...
end
module ZoneFun (Prop : PROP) = struct
  type t =
    { i: int;
      pal: ZonesEEA.t }
  ...
end

(* zones.ml *)
module ZonesFun (Zone: ZONE) = struct
  type t = Zone.t list
  ...
end
```

Therefore, the functors would allow me to build modules:

```
(* modules.ml *)
open EEA
open Zone
open Zones
module ZoneEEA = ZoneFun(EEA)
module ZonesEEA = ZonesFun(ZoneEEA)
```

However, the code does not work because there is a recursion: `ZoneFun` requires `ZonesEEA.t`, which comes from `ZoneEEA`, thus `ZoneFun`...

Does anyone have an idea to restructure the code to realize this recursion?

Comment: Would it be OK if you abstracted the type of field `pal` in `ZoneFun.t` or does the implementation of `ZoneFun` depend on that?  What I'm basically asking is, can you not remove the dependency of `ZoneFun` upon `ZonesEEA`?

Comment: The implementation of `ZoneFun` doesn't really depend on `pal`, but I do want `ZoneEEA.t` to have a field `pal` which is of type `ZonesEEA.t`. I don't know exactly what you mean by "abstracted the type of field `pal` in `ZoneFun.t`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of recursion across modules.  This creates a circular dependence, and cannot be done like that in OCaml.  However, if you can abstract over the type of `pal` in `ZoneFun`, you can do the trick.  I'm adding one more parameter to the `ZoneFun` functor, from which the type of `pal` will be taken.  I'm calling this parameter `Z` and I'm giving it the type `ZONES`, as it will be later instantiated with `ZonesEEA`.

```
(* zone.ml *)
module type ZONES = sig
  type t
  ...
end

module ZoneFun (Prop : PROP) (Z : ZONES) = struct
  type t =
    { i: int;
      pal: Z.t }
  ...
end
```

Then, `ZoneEEA` and `ZonesEEA` will be mutually recursive modules:

```
(* modules.ml *)
open EEA
open Zone
open Zones

module rec ZoneEEA : ZONE = ZoneFun(EEA)(ZonesEEA)
and ZonesEEA : ZONES = ZonesFun(ZoneEEA)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Several modules including `EEA` have the same module type `PROP`, `PROP` is necessary for me. `ZoneFun` and `ZonesFun` are used to build modules of type `ZONE` and `ZONES`. I guess you suggest me to change `ZoneFun` to `module ZoneFun (Prop: PROP) (ZS: ZONES) = struct type t = { i: int; pal: ZS.t }`, but in this case how can we initiate `ZONESEEA` which is recursive? Can we write `module ZoneEEA = ZoneFun(EEA)(ZonesEEA)` followed by `module ZonesEEA = ZonesFun(ZoneEEA)`?

Comment: Does `PROP` include a type `t`?  If yes, you don't need the two parameters to the functor, you can just use `PROP` there, instead of `ZONE`.

Comment: `PROP` does include a type `t`... please note that the type of `pal` is `ZonesEEA.t`(with a `s`) or `ZS.t`, instead of `Z.t`...

Comment: Thank you very much for your update... I didn't know `module rec` which permits recursive modules. Once again, one detail is, the type of `pal` should be `ZonesEEA.t` instead of `ZoneEEA.t`. May I write for instance `module rec ZoneEEA = ZoneFun(EEA)(ZonesEEA) and ZonesEEA = ZonesFun(ZoneEEA)`?

Comment: Right, sorry, didn't pay attention to your update before.  I fixed it now.  Notice that you have mutually recursive modules now.

Comment: Cool... I am going to adapt my code to this structure and test it... By the way, in my code `ZoneEEA : ZONE` and `ZonesEEA : ZONES` and `ZoneFun` will be `: PROP -> ZONES -> ZONE`. Thank you.